# Dynamically add panes and series to gauge, Update Options on the respective Panes and series from form

Tags: highcharts, series, gauge, pane

I had an requirement with gauge Chart -

```
$(function () {

var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Sample Title'
    },

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickAmount: 2,
        title: {
            y: -70,                
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};

// The speed gauge
$('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'Speed'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}));

// The RPM gauge
$('#container-rpm').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'RPM'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'RPM',
        data: [1],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
        }
    }]

}));

// Bring life to the dials
setTimeout(function () {
    // Speed
    var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts(),
        point,
        newVal,
        inc;

    if (chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }

    // RPM
    chart = $('#container-rpm').highcharts();
    if (chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.random() - 0.5;
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 5) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }
}, 2000);});
```

In the above example you can see that title is printing two times, But I need single title to be displayed at the center.

So I got solution that instead of creating multiple charts create single chart with multiple panes and series objects as shown in below link.

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
     chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',   
        height: 200
    },
    
     title: {
        text: 'Sample Title1'
    },
    pane: [{
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: null,
        center: ['25%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    }, {
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: null,
        center: ['70%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    }],

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    
    yAxis: [{
         stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
              min: 0,
        max: 200,            
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickAmount: 2,
        title: {
            y: -70,
                    text: 'Speed'
        },
        pane:0,
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    }, {
         stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
              min: 0,
        max: 5,            
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickAmount: 2,
        pane:1,
        title: {
            y: 70,
            text: 'RPM'
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    }],
    
    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    },
    
    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
         yAxis: 0,
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }, {
        name: 'RPM',
        data: [1],
        yAxis: 1,
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
        }
    }]

});


 // Bring life to the dials

setInterval(function () {
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    if (chart.series) { // the chart may be destroyed
        var left = chart.series[0].points[0],
            right = chart.series[1].points[0],
            leftVal,
            rightVal,
            inc1 = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100),
            inc2 = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 3;

        leftVal = left.y + inc1;                    
        if (leftVal < 0 || leftVal > 200) {
            leftVal = left.y - inc1;
        }
        rightVal = right.y+inc2;
        if (rightVal < 0 || rightVal > 5) {
            rightVal = right.y - inc2;;
        }

        left.update(leftVal);
        right.update(rightVal);
        chart.redraw();
    }
}, 2000);});
```

Now the Proiblem is

1. In My charts i can have gauge or solid gauge or both.
2. I want to actually add the panes and series objects dynamically . How can I add that for series I have chart.addSeries() how about pane.

Also in my charts we have enabled a toolbar where we have some form where the users can filter the options like

1. show or hide title
2. change tickamount
3. change mintickinterval etc

how can i update these options to a particular pane or series when I am using multiple panes and multiple series

Please help me.

Comment: You can see the above codes in the below JS fiddle links in the same order  
[First Code](http://jsfiddle.net/chandram97/zw0sujo2/2/)  
[Second code](http://jsfiddle.net/chandram97/do60mz99/1)